# Queuing up (via API) Facebook page posts so that they are posted at a particular time?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-integration, scheduling

Is there a way to schedule future posts to a [Facebook Business Page](http://www.facebook.com/help/pages) via the Facebook API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can now schedule posts for a Facebook page.

> You can prepare a post and schedule it to appear later by adding a date and time in the future before you post it. You can schedule a post up to 6 months in advance in 15-minute intervals.
>
> From your Page's sharing tool:
>
> - Choose the type of post you want to add to your Page  * Click the
>     clock icon in the lower-left of the sharing tool  * Choose the future
>     year, month, day, hour and minute when you'd like your post to appear
>
>   - Click Schedule

[image: Schedule]

> If you choose a date in the past, the post will appear immediately at the appropriate place on your Page's timeline. All times correspond to the current time zone you're in.

<sub>Source: Basics » Explore Popular Features » Facebook Pages » [How do I schedule a post to appear on my Page later?](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=389849807718635#How-do-I-schedule-a-post-to-appear-on-my-Page-later?)</sub>

Comment: Ooh... this I like for Facebook specific things. Thanks!

Comment: (via the Facebook API?)

Comment: @leeand00 no API needed.

Comment: @leeand00 in addition you are asking on an end user site. So the only answers you will get are for end users, not programming or API related.

Comment: Oh okay good point, over to StackOverflow then...

Comment: You'd probably get bonus points if you reference this question when building your SO question.

Answer (score 2):

[HootSuite](http://hootsuite.com/) Allows you to do this. There is both a free & paid version.

Comment: The last time I looked at HootSuite it didn't have Facebook support yet, thanks!

Comment: @leeand00 Yes it has Facebook and many others as well.

Comment: (via the Facebook API?)